# WPF Adding an item to a BindingList not update another Property in Viewmodel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, bindinglist

I have this code in my viewmodel (Singleton):

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the person list.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The person list.
    /// </value>
    public BindingList<Person> PersonList
    {
        get { return personList; }
        set
        {
            personList = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(PersonList));
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(PersonCount));
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the person count.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The person count.
    /// </value>
    public int PersonCount
    {
        get
        {
            return personList.Count();
        }
    }
```

When I add a Person to the BindingList it appears in the view correctly. A Change of one of the items of BindingList is shown correctly.
But the PersonCount is not updated and appears as "0".

The class Person is implemented like this:

```
public class Person : NotificationObject
{
    #region Fields

    private string name;
    private DateTime birthDate;
    private string lastName;

    #endregion // Fields

    #region Construction
    #endregion // Construction

    #region Attributes

    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set
        {
            name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Name));
        }
    }

    public string LastName
    {
        get { return lastName; }
        set
        {
            lastName = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(LastName));
        }
    }

    public DateTime BirthDate
    {
        get { return birthDate; }
        set
        {
            birthDate = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(BirthDate));
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Age));
        }
    }

    public int Age
    {
        get { return (DateTime.Now - birthDate).Days/365; }
    }

    #endregion // Attributes

    #region Operations
    #endregion // Operations

    #region Implementation
    #endregion // Implementation
} // class Person
```

Why the PersonCount is not updated and how to do it right?
What I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance,
Andreas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem in your code is, once you bind the 'PersonList' to the view model, the list object doesn't change unless you bind another list (what happens is just items are added or removed from the list), therefore the setter of the 'PersonList' property is not called & therefore "Notify property changed" doesn't trigger for 'PersonCount'.

However as the 'PersonList' is a **BindingList**, added/removed items are reflected in the UI.

**Solutions**

1) Register 'PersonList' to **ListChanged** event and call 'Notify Property Changed' in the event handler.

```
    public BindingList<Person> PersonList
    {
        get { return personList; }
        set
        {
            if (personList != null)
                personList.ListChanged -= PersonList_ListChanged;

            personList = value;

            if (personList != null)
                personList.ListChanged += PersonList_ListChanged;

            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(PersonList));
        }
    }

    public PersonsDashboardViewModel()
    {
        PersonList = new BindingList<Person>();

        PersonList.Add(new Person("Name1", "Lname1"));
        PersonList.Add(new Person("Name2", "Lname2"));
    }

    private void PersonList_ListChanged(object sender, ListChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(PersonCount));
    }
```

**OR**

2) Call 'Notify Property Changed' for 'PersonCount' where you add person items.

```
    public void AddPersonItem()
    {
        PersonList.Add(new Person("Sean", "Brendon"));
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(PersonCount));
    }
```

Comment: Your point 1) is dangerous! If you set `PersonList` one more time not in the constructor of `PersonsDashboardViewModel` the UI will not be updated. You have to more attentively read my answer

Comment: Your first solution did the work. 
I use a separate class with BusinessLogic to alter the viewmodel. The OnPropertyChanged method is private, too. 
Because of this I can`t use the OnPropertyChanged-Method of the viewmodel in this BusinessLogic.

Comment: Agreed with @Rekshino , you have to be careful when registering events. Registering for the 'ListChanged' event in the setter of 'PersonList' is straightforward.

Comment: Now it looks out better.

Answer (score 2):

You have to invoke `OnPropertyChanged(nameof(PersonCount));` where you modify the list. If it's not possible, then you have to subscribe to `CollectionChanged` for `PersonList` in setter and invoke `OnPropertyChanged(nameof(PersonCount));` in event handler.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My Personlist is instantiated in the constructor respectively in a reset-method to reset the viewmodel if needed. Is it what you mean with "in setter" ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @AndreasSusewind If you reassign the list in the reset method, then you have to unsubscribe the previous event handler and set the new one. Praboda has changed the answer, now is subscription in setter.